# How can I save a number to a list and use the same list (with any elements I added) at a later point?

Tags: lisp

This is my first program in LISP.  The language we are using is TinyLISP ( http://www.ugcs.caltech.edu/~rona/tlisp/tlspec.html ).

I am writing a program that gets a natural number num and returns the sum of all numbers from 0 to num (inclusive) that are multiples of either 3 or 5.

I have the function that determines if its a multiple of 3 or 5 written, but the part I am stuck on is where I am trying to save all of the variables I loop through into 2 different lists.

For example, if I am given a number (like 5), I start with the number 5, and then submit the number into my function that determines whether its a multiple of 3 or 5.  I want to store any variables returned as True to one list, then put any that are returned as NIL into another list.  The problem is that I cant figure out how to call on a list that I previously created.  The list needs to have all of the values from the previous times I called it as well.

How could I get this list problem fixed?

Comment: your question is best answered by reading an introduction book. Stackoverflow is not a programming language tutor.

Comment: In any case, it is incumbent on you to show us the code you have already, and demonstrate the attempts you have made to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Start with this:

```
(defun sumx (n m) (sumx_aux n m ....... ))
(defun sumx_aux (n m x s) (if (> x n) s (sumx_aux n m (+ x m) ..... )))
```

What does this `sumx` function do?

Fill in the blanks, figure out how you'd use it, and you're almost done. :)

If you need additional clues, read up on [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Basically, here it's about subtracting the numbers which were counted twice.

But if you insist on actually building your two lists, you'd do that by having two *accumulating parameters* in your recursive function, and adding a number you currently have to either one, or another, in two separate recursive calls inside `if`'s two clauses:

```
(defun foo_loop ( ... a b )
  ...
  (if ...
    (foo_loop ... (cons c a) b)
    (foo_loop ... a (cons c b))))
```